# Ternary operator in perl yields unexpected result when assigning a variable in the statement

Tags: php, perl, function, if-statement

I'm trying to make a transition from php to perl and expectedly running into some weirdness.  I cannot understand why one version of my code works vs another.

This fails:

```
sub tester
{
$return;
($_[0] < 10) ? $return = "youre a youngin" : $return = "youre an old person";
return $return;
}


print "how old are you?";
$a = <>;
chomp $a;

print  tester($a);  #both result in "youre an old person"
```

however this one works:

```
sub tester
{
    return ($_[0] < 10) ? "youre a youngin" : "youre an old person";
}


print "how old are you?";
$a = <>;
chomp $a;
print  tester($a);
```

what is the real difference here?!

Comment: That first example has some pretty suspect use of ternary operator (`?:`) going on...

Comment: Doesn't `=` takes precedence over `?:` braking this up?

Comment: Well, what's the error message?

Comment: @Jonah: and that has what to do with this question?

Comment: @ysth: everything.  What is "this fails" supposed to mean?  I suppose it would just be totally obvious to someone who knows Perl, but one should always give the details of the problem.

Comment: @Jonah: my comment was addressed to a different comment by you that has since been deleted.

Answer (score 11):

It is related to Perl's operator precedence. In Perl,

```
($_[0] < 10) ? $return = "youre a youngin" : $return = "youre an old fart";
```

is same as

```
( ($_[0] < 10) ? $return = "youre a youngin" : $return ) = "youre an old fart";
```

notice the paren binds to the FRONT.

and this leads to another confusing feature of Perl: conditional lvalues: You can do this
`(CONDITION ? $ASSIGN_A_IF_CONDITION_IS_TRUE : $ASSIGN_B_IF_CONDITION_IS_FALSE) = 2`

Here is a fix

```
($_[0] < 10) ? ($return = "youre a youngin") : ($return = "youre an old fart");
```

http://codepad.org/MxBAy7wy

EDIT:

However, most people would write

```
$return = ($_[0] < 10) ? "youre a youngin" : "youre an old fart";
```

, saving the redundancy of typing the variable twice.

According to Perl and PHP docs, Perl `?:` is right-associative and PHP `?:` is left-associative. (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html ) (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php )

Comment: I know nothing of Perl, but surely it supports something a bit more canonical like `$return = (cond ? a : b)` instead of `cond ? ($return = a) : ($return = b)`?

Comment: yes, that works and saves character count. (I was trying to fix what he was trying to express so I left his form)

Comment: @SHiN: Oh, I wasn't thinking of character count!  But this is the canonical usage of the ternary operator in all the languages that support it.  The OP's usage is highly non-standard (unless it's a Perl idiom), so probably best to avoid it.

Comment: You can get Perl to show you precedence with B::Deparse.  Run your program with `perl -MO=Deparse,-p whatever.pl` and it will display the code with implied parenthesis included.

Comment: associativity has nothing to do with it; it's a difference in precedence (where php has some odd rule making = higher precedence in some cases)

Answer (score 4):

Ah, you've discovered why `?:` is a bad idea except in trivial cases.

Operator precedence is the problem.  You most likely want to do this:

```
$return = ($_[0] < 10) ? "you're a youngin'" : "you're an old fart";
```

There are a few other issues with your code, though.

- You should declare your variables.  They aren't declared on first use as in PHP; you do it explicitly with the `my` operator.
- You should always, always, *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` in Perl code.  These pragmas disable ancient Perl shenanigans and warn about suspicious operations that might be bugs.
- The first line of a function should usually be unpacking `@_`; there's very little reason to use `$_[0]` directly in a function.  (And it's dangerous to do so, since `@_` is aliased; you could change the caller's variables!)

So you probably want something more like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub tester {
    my ($age) = @_;
    if ($age < 10) {
        return "you're a youngin'";
    }
    else {
        return "you're an old fart";
    }
}

print "how old are you? ";
my $age = <>;
chomp $age;

print tester($age);
```

Note that `my $x = ...` declares a single variable and assigns a single value, whereas `my ($x, $y, $z) = ...` declares multiple variables and unpacks a list into them.

`my` variables are called lexical and only exist within the block where you declare them; they aren't function-scoped like PHP variables.  Actually you should probably just read about them in [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
sub tester
{
   return ($_[0] < 10) ? "You're a young'un" : "You're an oldie";
}
```

then you get the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's a precedence thing.

```
($_[0] < 10) ? ($return = "youre a youngin") : ($return = "youre an old fart");
```

...works better.

But honestly, no serious Perl programmer would write it like this.  First, they would put the following at the top of their program:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Second, they would put the argument into a local:

```
sub tester {
    my $arg = shift;
```

Third, they would write the conditional in one of two ways:

```
if ($arg < 10) {
    $return = "you're a youngin";
}
else {
    $return = "you're an old fart";
}
```

If they came from a Lisp background, they would probably dispense with the $return variable and just write:

```
return $arg < 10 ? "you're a youngin" : "you're an old fart";
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, operator precedence.

Comment: Would you care to expand on that?

Comment: Assignment has low precedence, lower than that of the ternary operator.

Answer (score -4):

I believe `$return;` is a syntax error. You don't need to declare it - variables in perl and php are scopeless.
In addition `=` takes precedence over `?:` so you need to add `()` to both assignments.

Comment: This is woefully incorrect.  You absolutely SHOULD declare everything in Perl; otherwise all variables are globals!

Comment: @Eevee C'mon now, it might be dynamic `local` ;-)

Comment: You should declare it, but with `my $return;`  and of course `use strict;` at the beginning of the script to enforce it. Not doing so is a pretty poor practice *because* you have no scope to your variables.

Comment: No, they are function specific and not global.

Comment: Incorrect.  Perl does not have function-scoped variables.  It has package globals (`our` or unrecognized names without `strict`) and block-scoped lexicals (`my` or `state`).  And a variable name alone isn't a syntax error, either; it'll raise a "void context" warning under `warnings`, though.

Comment: @Dani: Please have a look at perldoc perlsub (the document from Perl's POD).  You keep stabbing at discussing scoping, but your assertions seem to be way off base.